# How do I serve dynamic content in a dashboard?

Tags: python, html, apache, nginx

I'd like to poll servers/network devices via SNMP/ICMP/SSH and serve up content about each device in a web browser to a user. Things like uptime, CPU usage, etc. What's a good way to do this?

Would I store the data in a db and then present it the framework of my choosing?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use monitoring tools for do that.
If you need alerting use tool like nagios or zabbix.
If you don't need alerting you can setup tool like munin o cacti.

Comment: I'm aware of these tools...I'd like to do this myself for fun

Comment: ok then you need to devel it, i suggest you to use python for to do that

Comment: I know it can be done in python and that is a good start. I'm interested in the entire stack. I am thinking something like flask/django with nosql.